# Об употреблении бинарного и иных "либо"

Tags: семантика

Предположим, что на столике лежат туз, король, дама, валет.

Верно ли, что:

- указание "Возьми туза либо короля." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля.",
- указание "Возьми туза, либо короля, либо даму." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму.",
- указание "Возьми туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета."?

P.S. Дорогие филологи, я не способен ответить на все ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемый Галактион. Я вижу вам не совсем ясна суть этих союзов. Прочитайте здесь : http://rusgram.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#511 . Надеюсь , вам все станет ясно. Если все же останутся неясные вопросы, пишите, обсудим вместе.

Comment: Уважаемый, Серж. Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Указание "Возьми туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, либо десятку." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, либо десятку."

Указание "Возьми туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, либо десятку, либо девятку." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, либо десятку, либо девятку."

Указание "Возьми туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, либо десятку, либо девятку, либо восьмерку." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, либо десятку, либо девятку, либо восьмерку."

Указание "Возьми туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, либо десятку, либо девятку, либо восьмерку, либо семерку." означает указание "Возьми либо туза, либо короля, либо даму, либо валета, либо десятку, либо девятку, либо восьмерку, либо семерку."

Указание "Выпей йаду либо цикуты" означает указание "Выпей либо йаду, либо цикуты".

Если что — пишите, обсудим.

Comment: "Если что".